# Bind data from database to dropdownlist using asp.net mvc 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have problem with the data that I select from table tblemployee that I want to bind it to the dropdownlist.

**model**

```
 public class UserModels
{
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Employee { set; get; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Education() {

        var query = (from e in context.tblEmployee_Employee
                     select new
                     {
                         empID = e.Code,
                         EmpName = e.NameEng
                     }
                              ).ToList();

        var model = new UserModels();
        var _Emp = query;
        foreach (var item in _Emp)
        {
            model.EmployeeCode = item.empID;
            model.EmployeeName = item.EmpName;
            model.Employee = new SelectList(_Emp, "EmpName", "EmpName");

        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

**View**

```
 <%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.EmployeeName, Model.Employee, "select EmployeeName")%>
```

And I got the error message "Object reference not set an instance of an object".Anyone know please kindly tell me how to solve it.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
public ActionResult Education() 
{
    var model = new UserModels();
    model.Employee = context
        .tblEmployee_Employee
        .ToList()
        .Select(e => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = e.Code.ToString(),
            Text = e.NameEng
        });
    return View(model);
}
```

And make sure that your view is strongly typed to the `UserModels` view model and then:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.EmployeeName, 
    Model.Employee, 
    "select EmployeeName"
) %>
```

Comment: I have the error on the view model"<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.EmployeeName,Model.Employee,"select EmployeeName") %>".It shows the error is "Object reference not set an instance of an object"

Comment: Make sure that you have passed a model when returning your view: `return View(model);` and that this model's Employee property is assigned a value. You should do the same in your POST action.